# How to avoid additional request for model data assigned to "dataSources"? (Component-preload.js)

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I'm defining a JSON data source in my `manifest.json` as follows (only relevant parts shown):

```json
{
  "_version": "1.8.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "myAppID",
    "dataSources": {
      "application_datasource": {
        "uri": "/model/application.json",
        "type": "JSON"
      }
    }
  }
},
"sap.ui5": {
  "models": {
    "application": {
      "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
      "dataSource": "application_datasource"
    }
  }
}
```

This works quite well; the JSON is loaded from the webserver.
When using the UI5-Tooling to build the app, I can see that the `/model/application.json` is actually included in the `Component-preload.js` under the key `"/myAppID/model/application.json"`.

When loading the application from the `dist`-folder, the app still hits the webserver for the `/model/application.json` and is not pulling it from the `Component-preload.js`.

What am I missing here to make it use the already in memory existing data? As far as I can see, the `manifest.json` itself is already pulled from the `Component-preload.js`.

Comment: Do you happen to have `"preload": true` in the `"application"`-model definition?